# Commutation techniques in SCR

Tags: power-electronics, commutation

I read in a textbook that "Commutation Time is more in Current Commutation compared to Voltage Commutation".Kindly Elaborate. [image]

Comment: Please give some context to your question. (1) The name and authors of the textbook + page number. (2) Explain what you understand or what you think the statement means. That way the answers can just address your misconceptions rather than spend time writing stuff you already know.

Comment: Think of the utility inductance

Comment: Elaborate your question with a source document that is readable on the internet or take a picture and post it. Have you done any research into this at all?

Comment: I am reposting the question with the text.

Comment: I certainly know about different methods of commutating inverters, choppers, having SCR as the switching element. However how the above conclusion is written is certainly out of blues for me.

Comment: @Jibe. Don't repost. Use the edit link under your question and rotate the image properly before uploading it. Please delete the other post.

Comment: @Jibe its associated with the supply inductance. Just because the voltage has dropped, doesn't mean the supply inductance won't keep the current flowing and thus delays the commutation of the SCR's